# What algorithm would I use for determining the progress of a rectangle exiting the bounds of a larger rectangle? Is there a name for this?

Tags: algorithm, math, progress-bar, progress

I'm having a great deal of trouble coming up with an algorithm to state the progress of a small rectangle leaving a larger rectangle.

The smaller rectangle begins centered in the larger:

```
----------
|        |
|        |
|  ----  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  ----  |
|        |
|        |
----------
```

As part of the game, the user can then "throw" the smaller rectangle outside the larger rectangle that it's contained within. If they throw it out completely, they win.

I want to have somewhat of a progress meter for how close they are to having it out. It's defined as "out" if the smaller rectangle has no point inside the larger rectangle.

I know progress is somewhat abstract in this case, especially with direction coming into play. The way I want it to work is basically as a function of the distance from the center. If they bring it closer to the center, progress decreases, but if it's brought away, progress increases. You're obviously given a vector representing the velocity/trajectory as well.

This would be somewhat of a trivial algorithm if both shapes were squares, as moving in whatever direction would have a basically static progression, but with them both being rectangles of any possible size and aspect ratio, progress in different directions is slower than others. (For example in the upper diagram, pushing it out via the top and bottom requires more movement than the sides, so it would progress slower as it moves up or down.)

I'm at wit's end trying to figure this one out. Is there a name for such a problem I could perhaps research? I'm using the dot product to find if the object is moving closer or further away, and considered using trigonometry and the angles of velocity, but I keep falling short.

Comment: The only way to solve this is with trigonometry and angles. Basically, given the angle which represents the direction of motion, you need to compute the distance needed so that either the x coordinates, or the y coordinates, don't overlap. You also need to compute the distance travelled so far. The ratio of those two distances is the progress.

Comment: You might have use of "axis aligned bounding box" theory.

Comment: Are the sides of smaller rectangle parallel to the sides of larger rectangle ?

Comment: So there is no rotation?

Answer (score 1):

If all these values are positive, small rectangle is inside the big one (or intersection takes place)

```
q = (Big.Right - Small.Left)
p = (Big.Left - Small.Right)
r = (Big.Top - Small.Bottom)
s = (Big.Bottom - Small.Top)
```

Then find minimal value from these ones  - they are times before exit:

```
qT = q / Velocity.X   //direction
pT = p / Velocity.X
rT = r / Velocity.Y
sT = s / Velocity.Y
```

Comment: What do these variables represent exactly?

Comment: Big.Right - right coordinate of larger rectangle etc. qT - time parameter denoting a moment when smaller rectangle, moving with given velocity (in given direction), will leave larger one.

Answer (score 0):

At any time, you know the co-ordinates of smaller rectangle. Also, bigger one is static.

Let the smaller rectangle be represented by: `(x1,y1)` (bottom left) and `(x2,y2)` (top right).

So, its center will be: `((x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2)` => `(a,b)`

Similarly, center of larger rectangle with co-ordinates: `(X1,Y1)` and `(X2,Y2)` will be: `((X1 + X2)/2, (Y1 + Y2)/2)` => `(A,B)`

If at any time:

```
abs(A-a) >= (x2-x1)/2 + (X2-X1)/2
          OR
abs(B-b) >= (y2-y1)/2 + (Y2-Y1)/2
```

`abs()` means absolute difference.

smaller rectangle is out of the bigger one. (equality means touches).